# Extract object from xml to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<det nItem="1">
    <prod>
        <cProd>222</cProd>
    </prod>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
    <prod>
        <cProd>888</cProd>
    </prod>
</det>'

SELECT
    det.value('@nItem', 'varchar(max)') as nItem,
    det_prod.value('(cProd)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as cProd
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/det') AS det(det),
    @XML.nodes('/det/prod') AS det_prod(det_prod)
```

It returns this result set:

```
nItem   cProd
-------------
   1    222
   1    888
   2    222
   2    888
```

but I want this returned like this:

```
 nItem  cProd
 -------------
   1    222
   2    888
```

Is there a way to do it without parse each `<det>` as a single xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are CROSS JOINing the nodes.  Instead use CROSS APPLY to join each `det` node to its related `prod` nodes. EG:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = 
'<det nItem="1">
    <prod>
        <cProd>222</cProd>
    </prod>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
    <prod>
        <cProd>888</cProd>
    </prod>
</det>'

SELECT
    det.value('@nItem', 'varchar(max)') as nItem,
    det_prod.value('(cProd)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as cProd

FROM
    @XML.nodes('/det') AS det(det)
CROSS APPLY
    det.det.nodes('prod') AS det_prod(det_prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `cross join` you need

```
SELECT
    det.value('@nItem', 'varchar(max)') as nItem,
    det.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as cProd
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/det') AS det(det);
```